# Pm2/forever angular universal server start throws buffer is deprecated error

Tags: angular-universal

I converted my angular project to angular universal (using @ng-toolkit/universal), and I was able to build and run using the below comments without any issue in both local and server:

```
npm run build:prod
npm run server
```

When I am trying to run using pm2/forever load balancer, I am getting the below exception, so it is not at all starting/running only:

> (node:15922) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due
>   to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(),
>   Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.

I updated both npm / ng and tried, but still no luck.

I also googled the error, and it seems few things are deprecated in the npm packages, where as I can't do anything here as it is angular universal project and server.js files are not created from my side. (all from ng-toolkit/universal) only.

Can someone help me here please?

Comment: Same error here. It seems that all my node_modules are OK, but is 

npm run build:ssr
npm run serve:ssr

generates deprecated "Buffer" calls, so i'm lost : )